# C++ class multiple inheritance error

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax-error, multiple-inheritance

I have been working on multiple inheritance. I have made a program but it keeps giving me an error such as Human::getInfo is ambiguous. How do I solve the problem
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Man{
protected:
    std::string name;
public:
    void getInfo(string hName){
        name = hName;
    }
    void showInfo(){
        std::cout << "Your name is: " << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "And you are a MAN" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Women:public Man{
public:
    Women(){}
    void Women_showInfo(){
        std::cout << "Your name is: " << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "And you are a Women" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Human:public Women, public Man{
public:
    Human(){}
};
int main(){
    //local variables
    string choice;
    string name;
    //class object
    Human person;
    //user interface
    cout << "What your name: " ;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Are you a [boy/girl]: ";
    cin >> choice;
    //saving name 
    person.getInfo(name); //ambiguous
    //if handler
    if (choice == "boy"){
        person.showInfo(); //ambiguous 
    }else if(choice == "girl"){
        person.Women_showInfo(); //works fine no error
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Also feel free to make changes in my code and would be even better if your could point out my mistake using my code.

Answer (score 2):

Your design is rather questionable, but the particular ambiguity arises because `Human` inherits from both `Woman` and `Man`, but `Woman` already inherits from `Man`.

So `Human` has two `getinfo()` functions in it - `Human::Man::getinfo()` and `Human::Woman::Man::getinfo()`. Unless you tell the compiler which one to use it doesn't know, and thus reports an error.

Comment: By adding to Human class declaration the following: `using Man::getInfo();`

Comment: If you don't mind can you show me using the code because it is hard to understand @Jonathan Potter

Comment: Instead of `person.getInfo(name);` you would do `person.Man::getinfo(name);` or `person.Woman::Man::getinfo(name);`.

Comment: I did do that but it says that Base class "Man" is ambiguous.@JonathanPotter

Comment: In fact it gives me the error Error: A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object